# Please reopen this question, I want to make a great answer

Tags: discussion

I have an excellent historical answer to this question:

[Why have some territorial annexations been rejected by the international community?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/22786/why-have-some-territorial-annexations-been-rejected-by-the-international-communi)

Comment: Aren't you able to reopen it yourself? You have 13324 reputation points

Comment: @Voitcus I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I find the question to be more political than historical and too broad in general. You could, however, ask a new question (perhaps better worded / more attuned to your intended answer) *and answer that yourself*. There's a checkbox for doing that as you write the question:

[image]